# Jacobian of a diffeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces

I'm trying to understant exercise $(4)$, chapter $5$, from Montiel-Ros's *Curves and Surfaces* to which there is a hint at the end of the chapter:

[image]

Hint:
[image]

I've understood everything from the hint, except for the last two lines. More precisely, this equality:
$$|\text{Jac}(\phi)|(p)=\frac{|\det(Ae_1\,Ae_2\,Ap)|}{|Ap|^3}$$

How did he conclude this from the expression of $(d\phi)_p(v)$?

Comment: How does he define the Jacobian to begin with? I am familiar with the Jacobian of a map between Euclidean spaces. When working with non-Euclidean manifolds, the definition I know depends on the coordinates.

Comment: In exercise $13$, chapter $2$, he defines $|Jac\,f|(p):=|(df)_p(e_1)\wedge (df)_p(e_2)|$, where $f:S_1\to S_2$ and $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $T_pS_1$ (in this exercise, we prove that $|Jac\, f|$ does not depend on the choice of the orthonormal basis). Using this definition, I can't see how he concluded the last equation in the solution.